# With working code: simple neural network (`y = 2 * x`)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm a beginner with neural networks and machine learning (hence the simple `y = 2 * x` that I want the model to learn). I explain what I know first, with the minimal working example at the end.

The generator function simply outputs the pair `(x, y)` where `y = 2 * x`, batched in groups of `batch_size`:

```
generator = data_generator(batch_size=3)

print(next(generator))
# (
#    array([[0], [1], [2]]),
#    array([[0], [2], [4]]),
# )

print(next(generator))
# (
#    array([[3], [4], [5]]),
#    array([[6], [8], [10]]),
# )

print(next(generator))
# (
#    array([ [6],  [7],  [8]]),
#    array([[12], [14], [16]]),
# )
```

Since this is a linear function, the model only requires a single layer to learn `y = 2 * x`:

- input
- multiplier layer: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)` (where the weight should be `2` from `y = 2 * x`)
- output

To run the following code, you only need `pip install tensorflow==2.6.0`

Minimal working example (runs, but the accuracy is always near 0):

```py
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def data_generator(batch_size):
    start = 0
    end = start + batch_size

    while True:
        x = np.arange(start, end)
        y = 2 * np.arange(start, end)

        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
        y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=-1)

        yield x, y

        start += batch_size
        end = start + batch_size

        # Randomly divide so that we get repeated data points
        # if random.random() < 0.5:
        #     start //= 2


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

batch_size = 32

generator_training = data_generator(batch_size)
generator_testing = data_generator(batch_size)

model.fit(
    x=generator_training,
    validation_data=generator_testing,
)
```

I've tried the following to make the accuracy increase to no avail:

- make `batch_size` for `generator_testing` smaller than the `batch_size` for `generator_training` so that the testing will usually be on data that's already been trained on
- use `if random.random() < 0.5: start //= 2` so that the training will get some data points more than once
- adding more `Dense` layers
- changing number of neurons in each `Dense` layer
- divide all `x` and `y` values by a large number (`1000000`) so that the values will be between `0` and `1` (at least in the beginning)

Why is the training giving an accuracy of `10e-4` or lower and what should I do to make the neural network learn `y = 2 * x`?

Comment: This is a regression problem. Accuracy is meaningless for regression problems. I would advise that you look into ML theory first and decide what an appropriate loss function and metric could be.

Comment: The model will not train if you do not use an appropriate loss function, here binary crossentropy makes no sense, you should use mean squared error.

Answer (score 1):

- For a task like this there is no need for a generator you could have directly passed the numpy array
- The generator is also is an infinite loop so the model keeps getting new
  data and stays on the same epoch
- The model is also way too simple.
- For the model to improve it must update its weights based on previously encountered training data, but since the generator keeps generating new data and its stuck on the first epoch there is no improvement.

---

- The data here is integer but the model will give predictions of floating type and so the comparision is unreliable hence the accuracy is not a good measure of performance.
- The loss will tell us how close our model is to the actual value.
- If you want the comparision to work you have to create a custom training loop https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch

---

The code below has

- A dataGenerator using the Sequence API
- Used a different model
- Added activation functions to the layers
- Used mean square error loss function

---

```
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import regularizers
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, x, y, batch_size=32):
        'Initialization'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.x) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        data = self.x[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        labels = self.y[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        return data, labels

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape = (1,)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(1))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='mse', metrics=['loss'])

# Print the model summary
model.summary()

# train data
x = np.arange(0, batch_size * 100)
y = 2 * np.arange(0, batch_size * 100)
train = DataGenerator(x, y, batch_size)

n_epochs = 100
batch_size = 32

history = model.fit(train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=n_epochs,)

# plot loss during training
plt.figure()
plt.title('Loss / Mean Squared Error')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(x, y,)
plt.title('Original data')

y_predict_train = tf.math.ceil(model.predict(x))
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(x, y_predict_train,)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('prediction')
plt.title('Predictions')

plt.show()

# test data
x_test = np.arange(batch_size * 1000, batch_size * 1500)
y_test = 2 * np.arange(batch_size * 1000, batch_size * 1500)

# floor gives the lower end of the floating point number ex. 4.560 will give 4
# you could also use ceil function ex 4.560 will give 5
y_predict_test = tf.math.floor(model.predict(x_test))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(x_test, y_test,)
plt.title('Test data')

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(x_test, y_predict_test,)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('prediction')
plt.title('Predictions')
plt.show()

q = model.predict( np.array( [10,200, 360, 1000] ) )
print(q)
print(tf.math.floor(q))
```

Comment: Note that the only really important thing here is the loss function (and possibly the data generation, haven't looked at it). Since the asker is only trying to approximate `y = 2x`, there is no need for hidden layers.

Comment: @xdurch0 I have tried the code provided by this answer and updating my code to use MSE, and you are correct that simply updating the loss function works